# Dynamic JPA CriteriaBuilder for hierarchical data

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a hierarchical data structure as following Where nodes are mapped to the parent node as following:

```
@Entity
public class Node implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    private long id;

     @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
     private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany    
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")    
    public List<Node> children = new LinkedList<Node>();

}
```

So for example lets say I have the following data:

```
          [A]
          / \
         /   \
        /     \
     [B]      [C]
     / \        \
    /   \        \
  [D]   [E]      [F]
          \
           \
           [G]
```

Now I want to build a dynamic query in JPA CriteriaBuilder that can query for any node and return the results of its children as well. For example if I query for B, I get the following results:

- B
- D
- E
- G

And, if I query for E, I get:

-E
 -G

And so on...

Comment: You would need to know the depth of the data to do that, right? But how would you be able to know the depth without looking at the data first? I always make this sort of thing with recursive lookups in the database.

Comment: No the depth is unknown for this data, it could be any number. What algorithm do u use to generate the query builder for this kind of data?

Comment: Why not just return E and process its children recursively using node.getChildren()?  There isn't an easy way to do this in a query.

Comment: That will be possible too, but I thought it might be possible to do it on the query level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using SQL Server 2012 as my database I have used with clause as following:

Assuming [E] node id is 8:

**Top to Bottom:**

```
WITH NODE_TREE AS(
     SELECT N.ID, N.PARENT_ID FROM NODE_TABLE N WHERE N.ID = 8
     UNION ALL
     SELECT N.ID, N.PARENT_ID FROM NODE_TABLE N
     INNER JOIN NODE_TREE NT
     ON N.ID = NT.PARENT_ID
)

SELECT * FROM NODE_TREE;
```

This will return a top-to-bottom list of nodes:

B, E, D, G

**Bottom to Top:**

```
WITH NODE_TREE AS(
     SELECT N.ID, N.PARENT_ID FROM NODE_TABLE N WHERE N.ID = 8
     UNION ALL
     SELECT N.ID, N.PARENT_ID FROM NODE_TABLE N
     INNER JOIN NODE_TREE NT
     ON N.PARENT_ID = NT.ID
)

SELECT * FROM NODE_TREE;
```

This will return a bottom-to-top list of nodes:

B, A

Comment: Nice as PostgreSQL has this, too. But how would this be done in JPA?

Comment: @gkephorus you can send a native query by providing the sql code along with the entity class as in `createNativeQuery(sqlString, klass).getResultList();`